# More Classes on Home

Tags: java, android, class, android-manifest, homescreen

I created an android project with several classes and also wrote them into the AndroidManifest.
I got this picture after the run.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh7bZ.png)
What can I do to appear on the table only once?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ChristusVivit"
    android:fullBackupOnly="false">

    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Impresszum"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".Fejezetek"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Please see [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. You are only showing us the end result of your work. For sure, there is a bug somewhere in your setup/code. But how do you think we can help with that ... when the only thing you give to us is that screenshot?

Comment: By creating an intent-filter with `action.MAIN` and `category.LAUNCHER` for each activity you actively tell Android that each one of those should have its own icon in the launcher. If you don't want that behavior, then don't add those filters.